# Jenkins Slave Issue - invalid stream header: 099EACED

Tags: linux, shell, jenkins, jenkins-agent, launch-agent

Jenkins 2.7.4 was installed in the RedHat Server and Linux Slaves is configured by Selecting "Launch agent via execution of command on master" option. We created a Shell script and it works fine in the Jenkins version 2.7.4.

Now we upgraded the Jenkins to 2.121.1. Now the same script throws an error

> <===[JENKINS REMOTING CAPACITY]===>Exception in thread "main"
>   java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: 099EACED     at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(ObjectInputStream.java:808)
>     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.(ObjectInputStream.java:301)     at
>   hudson.remoting.ObjectInputStreamEx.(ObjectInputStreamEx.java:48)
>     at
>   hudson.remoting.ChannelBuilder.makeTransport(ChannelBuilder.java:478)
>     at hudson.remoting.ChannelBuilder.negotiate(ChannelBuilder.java:433)
>     at hudson.remoting.ChannelBuilder.build(ChannelBuilder.java:354)    at
>   hudson.remoting.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:743)  at
>   hudson.remoting.Launcher.runWithStdinStdout(Launcher.java:691)    at
>   hudson.remoting.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:373)   at
>   hudson.remoting.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:283) ERROR: Connection
>   terminated ERROR: Unexpected error in launching an agent. This is
>   probably a bug in Jenkins java.io.IOException: Unexpected EOF     at
>   hudson.remoting.ChunkedInputStream.readUntilBreak(ChunkedInputStream.java:99)
>     at
>   hudson.remoting.ChunkedCommandTransport.readBlock(ChunkedCommandTransport.java:39)
>     at
>   hudson.remoting.AbstractSynchronousByteArrayCommandTransport.read(AbstractSynchronousByteArrayCommandTransport.java:35)
>     at
>   hudson.remoting.SynchronousCommandTransport$ReaderThread.run(SynchronousCommandTransport.java:63)
>   ERROR: Process terminated with exit code 1 java.io.IOException:
>   Unexpected EOF    at
>   hudson.remoting.ChunkedInputStream.readUntilBreak(ChunkedInputStream.java:99)
>     at
>   hudson.remoting.ChunkedCommandTransport.readBlock(ChunkedCommandTransport.java:39)
>     at
>   hudson.remoting.AbstractSynchronousByteArrayCommandTransport.read(AbstractSynchronousByteArrayCommandTransport.java:35)
>     at
>   hudson.remoting.SynchronousCommandTransport$ReaderThread.run(SynchronousCommandTransport.java:63)
>   Also:   hudson.remoting.Channel$CallSiteStackTrace: Remote call to
>   rtt-ci-euhrhd0036vdeas        at
>   hudson.remoting.Channel.attachCallSiteStackTrace(Channel.java:1741)
>         at hudson.remoting.Request.call(Request.java:202)       at
>   hudson.remoting.Channel.call(Channel.java:954)        at
>   hudson.slaves.SlaveComputer.setChannel(SlaveComputer.java:549)        at
>   hudson.slaves.SlaveComputer.setChannel(SlaveComputer.java:416)        at
>   hudson.slaves.CommandLauncher.launch(CommandLauncher.java:153)        at
>   hudson.slaves.SlaveComputer$1.call(SlaveComputer.java:288)        at
>   jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$2.call(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:46)
>         at
>   jenkins.security.ImpersonatingExecutorService$2.call(ImpersonatingExecutorService.java:71)
>         at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)      at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)         at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>         at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) Caused:
>   hudson.remoting.RequestAbortedException   at
>   hudson.remoting.Request.abort(Request.java:340)   at
>   hudson.remoting.Channel.terminate(Channel.java:1038)  at
>   hudson.remoting.SynchronousCommandTransport$ReaderThread.run(SynchronousCommandTransport.java:96)

If I disable the SSHD port in Manage Jenkins -> Configure Security, Then I can able to launch my slave. But In my script, I will trigger one job using Jenkins-cli.jar to copy the binaries from master to slaves. 
`java -jar jenkins-cli.jar -s http://localhost:8080 --ssh -user username -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa build RTT/RTT-CI-Tools/RTT-CI-Tools-Distribute -s -p SLAVE_REGEX=slave name` 
I'm getting a message as

```
"WARNING: No header 'X-SSH-Endpoint' returned by Jenkins"
```

and build is not getting triggered. I have also tried by replacing -ssh to -http in jenkins-cli.jar command,

`java -jar jenkins-cli.jar -s http://localhost:8080 -http -auth username:60b3450a883a2519592af84cdcd0d224 build $CI_JOB -s -p SLAVE_REGEX=$SLAVEHOST`

It triggers the job. Again unable to launch the slave machine,

> <===[JENKINS REMOTING CAPACITY]===>Exception in thread "main"
>   java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: 099FACED     at
>   java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(ObjectInputStream.java:808)
>     at java.io.ObjectInputStream.(ObjectInputStream.java:301)     at
>   hudson.remoting.ObjectInputStreamEx.(ObjectInputStreamEx.java:48)
>     at
>   hudson.remoting.ChannelBuilder.makeTransport(ChannelBuilder.java:478)
>     at hudson.remoting.ChannelBuilder.negotiate(ChannelBuilder.java:433)
>     at hudson.remoting.ChannelBuilder.build(ChannelBuilder.java:354)    at
>   hudson.remoting.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:743)  at
>   hudson.remoting.Launcher.runWithStdinStdout(Launcher.java:691)    at
>   hudson.remoting.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:373)   at
>   hudson.remoting.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:283) usage: ssh
>   [-1246AaCfgKkMNnqsTtVvXxYy] [-b bind_address] [-c cipher_spec]
>              [-D [bind_address:]port] [-e escape_char] [-F configfile]
>              [-i identity_file] [-L [bind_address:]port:host:hostport]
>              [-l login_name] [-m mac_spec] [-O ctl_cmd] [-o option] [-p port]
>              [-R [bind_address:]port:host:hostport] [-S ctl_path]
>              [-W host:port] [-w local_tun[:remote_tun]]
>              [user@]hostname [command] ERROR: Unexpected error in launching an agent. This is probably a bug in Jenkins ERROR:
>   Connection terminated java.io.IOException: Unexpected EOF

How to fix this issue

Answer (score 4):

## Unaltered stdin, unaltered stdout

I believe something in your script is tampering with stdin.

Your script should pass the **entire, unaltered** stdin stream to the Jenkins agent process.

## A universal solution

OP's command to establish a Jenkins session is different from mine, but regardless, you should split your launch script into 3 major parts:

**Set up:** no tampering with stdin or stdout in this part.

**Establish Jenkins session:** `java -jar jenkins-cli.jar ...`

**Tear down:** no tampering with stdin or stdout in this part.

```
#!/bin/bash

function set_up {
    # your set-up code here
}

function tear_down {
    # your tear-down code here
}

function main {
    # set-up (no stdin, no stdout)
    set_up "$@" < /dev/null > /dev/null || exit $?
    # establish Jenkins session
    java -jar jenkins-cli.jar -blah -blah -blah
    # tear-down (no stdin, no stdout)
    tear_down "$@" < /dev/null > /dev/null || exit $?
}
main "$@"
```

---

## But... why?

The job of your launch script is to establish an untampered communication channel (via stdin and stdout) between the master and the build agent.

```
              +------------+
"Hello Agent" |            |
   _ _    ----+            +----
    v               Hello Agent  ->
          ----+            +----
              |            |
              |            |  "Hello Master"
          ----+            +----   _ _
       <-  Hello Master             v
          ----+            +----
              |            |
              +------------+
                  launch
                  script
```

If this communication channel is tampered, Jenkins won't work.

```
              +------------+
"Hello Agent" |            |
   _ _    ----+            +-----------
    v            Hel PLZ SEND HELP!! t  ->
          ----+            +-----------
              |            |
              |            |  
          ----+            +----   | |
                                    ^
          ----+            +----
              |            |
              +------------+
                  launch
                  script
```

Some Unix commands may "swallow" the stdin of your launch script if you do not pipe anything into that command, and therefore "corrupt" the communication channel. Consider the following script.

```
#!/bin/bash

function keep_stdin_intact {
    printf 'I do not consume any stdin, ' >&2
    echo 'and I do not alter the original stdout.' >&2
}

function swallow_stdin {
    echo 'I swallow stdin. Did you see any hexdump below?' >&2
    read yn  # read consumed some stdin
}

echo 'yes' | { keep_stdin_intact; cat -; } | xxd
echo 'yes' | { swallow_stdin; cat -; } | xxd

echo "no you can't now :P" | { swallow_stdin < /dev/null; cat -; } | xxd
```

- The first `yes` got piped out and hex-dumped, because `keep_stdin_intact` did not tamper with stdin, in this case, the "yes" stream.
- The second `yes` was gone, because `swallow_stdin` consumed it, so `cat` has nothing to cat and `xdd` has nothing to read.
- By piping `/dev/null` to an stdin-swallowing command, we protected our own stdin.

## What's up with ssh?

`ssh` is one of the evil commands that swallow your stdin.

Let's say you want to remove some files on the build agent before `agent.jar` is run. Without the boilerplate, you may be tempted to write:

```
ssh $OPTIONS "$remote" 'sudo rm -rf /var/log/nginx/*'
ssh $OPTIONS "$remote" 'cd $HOME && java -jar agent.jar'
```

^ But this is wrong! The first `ssh` command will swallow your stdin, and the Jenkins session will have nothing to read.

The first `ssh` must be "silenced." Pass `/dev/null` as its stdin.

```
ssh $OPTIONS "$remote" 'sudo rm -rf /var/log/nginx/*' < /dev/null
ssh $OPTIONS "$remote" 'cd $HOME && java -jar agent.jar'
```

Comment: If I disable the SSHD port in Manage Jenkins -> Configure Security, Then I can able to launch my slave. But In my script, I will trigger one job using Jenkins-cli.jar to copy the binaries from master to slaves. 

`java -jar jenkins-cli.jar -s http://localhost:8080 --ssh -user username -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa build RTT/RTT-CI-Tools/RTT-CI-Tools-Distribute -s -p SLAVE_REGEX=slave name`

I'm getting a message as
"WARNING: No header 'X-SSH-Endpoint' returned by Jenkins" and build is not getting triggered

Comment: I believe something in your launch script is tampering with stdin. I have updated my answer. You may consider refactoring your script using the provided boilerplate.